# Applying the pool.starmap() function with multiple arguments on a dict which are both passed as arguments inside the .starmap()

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I'm currently trying to apply parallel processing on a script. The following is just to simulate the current script I am working on. Basically, I want to call the Pool.starmap() function on a function and a dictionary. The thing is, the function has multiple arguments.  I keep getting this error,

TypeError: read_books() takes 4 positional arguments but 6 were given

I've tried calling the function with the desired arguments, inside pool.starmap(function(arg1, arg2, ar3), dict)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import product

# dict - key as string, value as a list

library = {
    'horror': ['Book1', 'book2', 'book3'],
    'thriller': ['book3', 'book4', 'book5'],
    'romance': ['book4', 'book5', 'book6']
}

def read_books(group_friends, library_name, amount_of_hours, key):

    for friend in group_friends:
        print(f"friend {group_friends} visits the library to read {key} books")

    print(f"They are all at the library {library_name} and spend a total of {amount_of_hours} there.")


with mp.Pool(processes=len(library)) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(read_books, library)
```

I basically just want to execute the read_books function 3 times for each key-value pair

Comment: It is totally unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish. How, exactly, so you want your function to be called?

Comment: Sorry, about that, I was able to figure it out. I'll explain down below.

Comment: @FanonX Just so you know, adding your own answer is fine... if your own answer provides something more than what is already out there. Having 10 answers that say the same thing is not really useful, it's better to have one detailed answer instead. For example your answer gives no explanation as to why your initial approach was wrong and why you received that exception specifically. When answering make sure that your answers are  of value and as detailed as possible to completely answer the question, it's way easier to earn reputation and be more helpful to other people.

Answer (score 0):

`starmap` is equivalent to:

```
def starmap(func, iterable):
    for elem in iterable:
        yield func(*elem)
```

In your case `iterable` is a `dict` so it iterates over the keys and for each key it calls `read_books` with `*elem`, i.e. it puts one argument per character. so you end up calling, for example:

```
read_books('r', 'o', 'm', 'a', 'n', 'c', 'e')
```

`library` should be something like this for your code to work:

```
library = [
    ['horror', 'Book1', 'book2', 'book3'],
    ['thriller', 'book3', 'book4', 'book5'],
    ]'romance', 'book4', 'book5', 'book6']
]
```

You could also do:

```
pool.starmap(read_books, ((k, *vals) for k, vals in library.items()))
```

in modern python versions.

You cannot just use `library.items()` since in that case `starmap` would call the function with only two arguments: the key and the value (which happens to be a list).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. Sorry if my explanation was not clear.

```
library = [
    (['horror', 'Book1', 'book2', 'book3'], "library 1", 44, "key"),
    (['thriller', 'book3', 'book4', 'book5'], "library 2", 44, "ke6"),
    (['romance', 'book4', 'book5', 'book6'], "library 3, 55, "key3)
]
```

I was incorrectly passing in the iterable. I had to wrap the list of books inside a tuple in order to correctly apply the arguments to the function that was being passed into pool.starmap()

```
with mp.Pool(processes=len(library)) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(read_books, library)
```